# Give index on data

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr, grouping

Hope you can help me with my problem.

I would like to create an index on each group in my data.

The data looks like this.

```
ID X 
1 1 
1 2
1 1
1 2
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 1
2 2
```

I have tried to recode and the data but it gives me this result

```
group_by(X) %>% mutate(INDEX = seq_along())
```

It gave me this result.

```
ID X INDEX
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 2
1 2 2
1 1 3
1 2 3
1 3 1
2 1 4
2 2 4
2 3 2
2 4 1
2 1 5
2 2 5
2 3 3
2 1 6
2 2 6
```

However, I expected to get this result.

```
ID X INDEX
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 2
1 2 2
1 1 3
1 2 3
1 3 3
2 1 4
2 2 4
2 3 4
2 4 4
2 1 5
2 2 5
2 3 5
2 1 6
2 2 6
```

Comment: To clarify: Your index is the number of times that combination of ID and X have appeared so far?

Comment: Try `... index = cumsum(X == 1)`

Comment: you are close. `group_by(X) %>% mutate(INDEX = seq(n()))` should get you the result

Comment: It gave me the same result, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should first count the number of 'restarts':

```
nstarts <- length(df$X[df$X == 1])
```

Then you can assign an ID every time the counter restarts:

```
df$ID[df$X == 1] <- 1:nstarts
```

and fill the rest of the column with the same values:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- fill(df, ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grouping = 0
sapply(seq(1,nrow(X)),function(x){
  if(X[x,2] == 1){
    grouping <<- grouping + 1  
  }
  return(grouping)
})
```